# How to input multiple lines from a csv file to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to create an array where I want to store values from a CSV file to that array.

My code :

```
public static Trip[] readExistingFile(File inp) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inp);
        Trip[] trip_array = new Trip[5];

        //while loop to input file 

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            //separating values from csv
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            String mode = values[0];
            String origin = values[1];
            String destination = values[2];
            double duration = Double.parseDouble(values[3]);

            for (int i = 0; i < trip_array.length; i++) {

                if (mode.equals("Flight")) {

                    boolean meals = Boolean.parseBoolean(values[4]);
                    trip_array[i] = new Flight(duration, origin, destination, meals);
                    
                }
    
                if (mode.equals("Drive")) {
    
                    double gog = Double.parseDouble(values[4]);
                    trip_array[i] = new Drive(duration, origin, destination, gog);
                    
                }
    
                if(mode.equals("Train")){
    
                    String[] stops = new String[values.length-4];
                    for (int k = 4; k < values.length; k++) {
                        
                        for (int j = 0; j < stops.length; j++) {
    
                            stops[j] = values[k];
                            
                        }
    
                    }
    
                    trip_array[i] = new Train(duration, origin, destination, stops);
                }
                
            }
```

In running this code, only a single line is added multiple times. How do I add the other lines?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you nesting the for loop inside of the while loop? You should probably use one or the other, and create your new objects inside the loop.

Comment: can you use an existing CSV library? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: Remove the for loop, and include a check how far through you are through your trip_array so you don't get an Out Of Bounds exception if you have more than 5 lines in your input file.